# Shell scripts: diff command

Tags: shell, diff

I have a small question about the `diff` command. I am comparing two ascii files to check if there's a difference between them and print out the output to another ascii. However my problem is that the order of the contents of the files shouldn't matter, for example let's say we have:

`file1.txt` with

```
1  
2  
3  
4   
5  
6   
7
```

`file2.txt` with

```
1  
3      
2   
4
```

so that when i do a "diff" on them the output should just be:

```
5  
6  
7
```

i.e the order of the two files shouldn't matter, it should just print out the whatever it is that is different between the two files.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
comm -3 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to sort both the files and then input the files into diff command or comm command. There are many options for doing so.

Instead of providing a command that would do your job. I can provide you a link that can make you understand how it works.

Here it is [Click here](http://goo.gl/LOh2nm)